# Jquery & Ajax - GET request text not showing up on textbox, but shows on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have got a page where there is a text box which can be updated on keypress and is instantly saved to database as user is typing.

So here is my textarea:

```
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

What I want:

The user opens the same page twice in two different tabs, `tab1` and `tab2`. They are exactly the same pages, but just opened two times. Now, if the user goes to `tab1` and starts typing in the text area, it will instantly update and save to database, and with the GET request, it will show up on `tab2`. It is working great. I have set the interval to 1 second. So every time I type something on tab1, it will automatically replace the previous, old text over at `tab2` with the newer one.

Keep in mind that I am typing and replacing text in a text area.

Now this is where the issue begins: When the user is typing in `tab1` and decides to go to `tab2` and edit it, the changes made in `tab2` will not display in `tab1`, but the GET request is still successful. It will just not update the text area. And vice versa. Once the text area has been edited, neither of the text area's in either tab will update if the user types something.

To test it out, I created a div, `<div id="test"></div>` and this is consistent throughout both tabs. It updates every second on either tabs, regardless of which tab the changes were made.

My javascript code:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var interval = function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url('home/get') ?>",
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#text").text(html);
                    $("#test").text(html);
                },
            });
        };

        setInterval(interval, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I fixed it.

I don't know why it works, but replacing

`$("#text").text(html);`

with

`$("#text").val(html);`

fixed it.

I don't know why it works but it works.

Comment: **.val()** works on input elements which includes textarea. but **.text()** won't work on input elements.

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` is the jQuery method of getting value out of or into an input/textarea. It corresponds with the `.value` property in vanilla JS.
`.tex()` is for nodes that utilize `.textContent` property. I hope that helps clarify why the change you made works.

Answer (score 0):

As sagarthapa mentioned **.val()** works with input elements. Whereas **.text()** grabs "hidden" nodes called *DOMTextNode* in the DOM which a majority of elements have (but not input elements). If there are nested elements it will concatenate the child elements text nodes when reading. To my understanding when writing with **.text()** it will override all inner html and text nodes.